# Get FLV file URL from a webpage

Tags: php

I want to get FLV file url of the webpage with automation, is it possible? because that site has no autoplay, when i use GetFLV i get the url on when i press play button, i need to get url in php code'automatically, How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Retrieve the HTML of the page (using a library such as `cURL`)
2. Parse the retrieved HTML (using a library such as the PHP DOM)
3. Extract the relevant URL from the DOM tree

It is possible the URL was generated via JavaScript, in which case you'll also need to run a JS interpreter or close facsimile thereof.

P.S. - remember to check that doing this does not violate the web site's terms of service.